# WPF ListView not Binding to ViewModel Property

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to setup a listview that, after a call to the Azure GraphAPI will load a list of users.  Everything up to the binding of the data works.  The call to Graph works, the returned data works, all without issue.

I have a listview setup in a view:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NoPicUsers}"  >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Header="Display Name"
                        Width="200">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NoPicUsers.DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

The corresponding ViewModel has the following code:

```
 public class ContentPanelHomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<UserModel> _noPicUsers;//NotifyTask<List<UserModel>> _noPicUsers;
    public List<UserModel> NoPicUsers
    {
        get
        {
            return _noPicUsers;
        }
        set
        {
            _noPicUsers = value;
            
            //OnPropertyChanged Method is in ViewModelBase
            OnPropertyChanged("NoPicUsers");
            
        }
    }
    public ContentPanelHomeViewModel()
    {
        //NoPicUsers = new NotifyTask<List<UserModel>>.Create(GetNoPicUsersAsync());

        //NoPicUsers = NotifyTask.Create(GetNoPicUsersAsync);
        var users = GetNoPicUsersAsync();
        
    }

    private async Task<List<UserModel>>  GetNoPicUsersAsync()
    {
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GraphAPIServices.SignInAndInitGraph(AzureAppInfo.UserReadAll);
        List<UserModel> users = new List<UserModel>();
      
       var listOfUsers = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .Filter("accountEnabled eq true")
            .Select("displayname, id")
            .GetAsync();

        foreach (var user in listOfUsers)
        {
            UserModel azureUser = new UserModel();
            azureUser.DisplayName = user.DisplayName;
            azureUser.ObjectID = user.Id;

            users.Add(azureUser);
        }

        NoPicUsers = users;

        return users;

    }

}
```

My listview does not display any data and I cannot figure out why.  There are no reported errors and no binding errors reported when the WPF window loads so I'm not sure what would be the issue?

EDIT:  I've updated my code.  I'm implementing the NugetPackage Nito.Mvvm.  I get the same problem of no data binding to my list view if I set my NoPicUsers inside of the GetNoPicUsersAsync() the WPF window yells saying NoPicUsers property no found on object of Type UserModel.

So it appears that it thinks my ViewModel as a UserModel property instead of a List  property.  What would cause that?

In stepping through the code the task never seems to complete. The Task sits at Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{Null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}".

Comment: Can you bind an ItemsSource directly to a property of type NotifyTaskCompletion? Have you tried the traditional way of implementing a List property with change notifcation and assignment from an awaited method call?

Comment: I've tried just binding to a List<UserModel> Property and that doesn't work either.  I haven't setup change notification yet as I'm just trying to get it to display first.

Comment: A change notification would of course be required when the property's value changes after the view is initialized - which is what you are doing here with an async method.

Comment: I implemented the property changed and that fires as expected.  Still no list of data.  I did notice in stepping through that my async Task  sits at Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{Null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}".  This has to be the root of my whole problem, but I don't understand why the task hasn't returned anything.  I see no errors.  And the return variable in the async task has all the data, so the api gets called and executed.

Comment: You mean with `public List<UserModel> NoPicUsers { get; set; }` and `NoPicUsers = await GetNoPicUsersAsync();` plus firing PropertyChanged?

Comment: Just noticed `{Binding NoPicUsers.Result.DisplayName}`. That makes no sense. It should be `{Binding DisplayName}`.

Comment: That's what it is.  RIght now the property is a simple List<UserModel>.  I call the NotifyTaskCompletion, assign it to a var  and then assign the List<UserModel> to the var.results.  Strangly the var is null after the NotifyTaskCompletion has been called and ran.  Yet within that NotifyTaskCompletion the return line List<UserModel> variable is fully populated.

Comment: I was explicitly asking whether it worked without NotifyTaskCompletion, as you can see in my previous comments. Also note the wrong Binding Path.

Comment: How are you associating the VM to the Page's `DataContext`?

Comment: In my MainWindow I have DataTemplates for all my VMs associating them with the corresponding views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a threading issue where the UI is unaware of changes being made because the `Task` is being invoked on a separate thread since it is not awaited.

I suggest using an async event raised by the view model

```
public class ContentPanelHomeViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    private List<UserModel> _noPicUsers;//NotifyTask<List<UserModel>> _noPicUsers;
    public List<UserModel> NoPicUsers {
        get {
            return _noPicUsers;
        }
        set {
            _noPicUsers = value;
            
            //OnPropertyChanged Method is in ViewModelBase
            OnPropertyChanged("NoPicUsers");
        }
    }

    public ContentPanelHomeViewModel() {
        starting += onStarting;
        starting(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private event EventHandler starting = delegate { };
    private async void onStarting(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        starting -= onStarting; //optional

        // the following runs on background thread
        List<UserModel> users = await GetNoPicUsersAsync();

        // returned to the UI thread
        NoPicUsers = users; //notifies UI
    }

    private async Task<List<UserModel>>  GetNoPicUsersAsync() {
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = await GraphAPIServices.SignInAndInitGraph(AzureAppInfo.UserReadAll);
        List<UserModel> users = new List<UserModel>();
      
       var listOfUsers = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .Filter("accountEnabled eq true")
            .Select("displayname, id")
            .GetAsync();

        foreach (var user in listOfUsers) {
            UserModel azureUser = new UserModel();
            azureUser.DisplayName = user.DisplayName;
            azureUser.ObjectID = user.Id;

            users.Add(azureUser);
        }    
        return users;
    }

}
```

the `OnPropertyChanged` would have triggered the UI to update if it was invoked on the same thread as the UI. Because the view model trying to update the property on a background thread the UI was not getting the notification so was unaware that it needed to update.

By doing the heavy lifting on a background thread the UI is kept responsive while the work is being done. When the task returns to  the UI thread then the property can be updated so the UI can receive the event trigger to update itself.

There is also an issue with the binding declared in the UI. The cell template needs to bind to the property of the item, not the top level property

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NoPicUsers}"  >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn
                Header="Display Name"
                Width="200">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you for that!  I have a couple questions.  I would have thought the OnPropertyChanged for NoPicUsers would have trigged the UI to update?  How does that work with the delegate because when I comment out OnPropertyChanged, it doesn't work.   Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @FLAdmin the `OnPropertyChanged` would have triggered the UI to update if it was invoked on the same thread as the UI. Because you were trying to update the property on a background thread the UI was not getting the notification so was unaware that it needed to update. By doing the heavy lifting on a background thread you keep the UI responsive while the work is being done. When you return to  the UI thread then you update the property so the UI can receive the event trigger to update itself.